# Fire a static SOAP request from Java web application

Tags: java, soap

I have a requirement to call one of the secured web service(Https) from my java web application. We have received a static soap request (Complete soap message) which needs to be fired and get the authentication token for our communication. Now, the question is how do I fire this static soap request from Java? We have a restriction of not using Axis for some reason. How do we achieve this?

Comment: Why dont you use HttpsURLConnection and send your SOAP data.

Comment: Can you use other web containers other than axis? sending a static SOAP request sounds like a very bad idea...

Comment: do you have any useful resource or links which used HttpsURLConnection on how to map my static soap request message in that?                                 @ftom2: Our application is running on glassfish server. What is your suggestion then if I dont use a static soap request, because i have received the soap message from customers stating this will give me the security token to proceed.

Comment: From what i understand, you have a full structure of SOAP request that you should send, that same structure is usually produced by the web container of the application server (i.e. glassfish) so usually, when consuming a WEb service, you generate client stubs (there are quite a lot of frameforks to do that) and send the request, and the server takes care of authoring the soap request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to write an answer so I can elaborate on what i wrote in the comment.
Any Application server including Glassfish, comes with a web container bundeled. This web container is incharge of handling http requests and that includes web services request.

Also, Glassfish comes with a few bundeled scripts and one of them is for creating client stubs from WSDL files. If you use netbeans IDE it is quite easy, if not there is a script you can run manually for that in the bin folder.

Because you are using HTTPS, you'll also need to generate a keystore and place the certificate there (ask the service provider to give it to you).

I know it is more complicated, but it is also much more robust and once you have it running, making changes is much more easy and automated.

Comment: I'm not sure the web container has anything to do with outgoing web service calls. They are usually done by a framework such as JAX-WS, or (as someone suggested originally) by just opening a HTTP connection from your Java program.

Comment: You are right, But please note I wrote: "This web container is incharge of handling http requests and that includes web services request", with emphasis  on the word "request". I guess I could make it clearer. Anyway, it doesn't change the fact that it is better to use an actual webservice framework.